# MySQL Return least common rows based on another Table

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if I could get some help please? Apologies for the title, it was hard to summarise what I needed.

I have 2 tables, one contains a bank of questions and the other one stores people's responses to said questions. Both are linked by a unique identifier string.

What I need is to be able to order the questions in the question bank based on which ones have the least amount of entries in the answers table.

Is this easy to do? I can elaborate if this isn't clear enough or provide examples of tables etc... if needed.

Many thanks.

Comment: Examples of tables are welcome, SQL codes to create the tables with some contents are very welcome

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Here is a very dumbed down version of the tables I'm working with, they are too big to provide in full and I am short on time at this moment, so my apologies. You should be able to get what I mean from these though.

[Link](https://i.postimg.cc/ZnMqFY01/tables.png).

Basically, you will see that the questions regarding food have been answered more on the right hand table than the ones regarding the Gym, therefore when conducting my SQL query, I want it to prioritize the questions regarding the Gym since they have the least amount of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out using the below query, thanks for having a look at my question though guys.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Question_Bank.*,
(
    SELECT COUNT(ID)
    FROM Question_Answers
    WHERE Question_ID = Question_Bank.Question_ID
) AS cnt
FROM Question_Bank
JOIN Question_Answers
ORDER BY cnt ASC
```